# Orthogonal complement of a dense subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

I am stuck on how to complete my proof for part a, and I am also unsure whether my counterexample for question 2 is okay. I would really appreciate any help.

Q1) If M is a dense linear subspace of a Hilbert space X then $M^\bot=\{0\}$

Q2) If M is a linear subspace of a Hilbert space X such that $M^\bot=\{0\}$ then M is dense.

My attempt:

1. M dense $\implies$ any $x \in X$ is a limit of some sequence $y_n$, where each $y_n \in M$. Now assume that there exists some $y \in M^\bot$  such that $y \ne 0$. Then for each $m \in M$, $$0=\langle y,m \rangle = \langle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(y_n), m \rangle = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle y_n,m \rangle$$ by continuity of the inner product.
   But from here not sure how I can force a contradiction. is there anyway I can proceed or do I need a totally different approach?
2. False; take $X=\ell^{2}$, $M=\{x \in \ell^{2}$ such that $x_n = 0$ for all but finitely many $n$ }. Then $M^\bot = \{0\}$ and clearly $M$ is not dense in $\ell^{2}$.

Thank you !

Comment: (1) Approximate $y$.  (2) Why do you think $c_{00}$ is not dense in $\ell^2$?

Comment: @user10354138 (1) What do you mean by approximate y? (2) Ah, so my set is dense in $\ell^{2}$. I wasn't actually sure. Thank you

Comment: @duelspace "Approximate $y$" in this context means consider a sequence of elements from $M$ that converges to $y$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann isnt this what i've done? But I'm not sure how to proceed from this

Comment: You need to go "the other way". Note that 
$$
0 = \langle y, y_n \rangle \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle y,y_n \rangle = 0
$$

Comment: @duelspace The hint definitely could have been expressed more clearly

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh I see, thank you!

Comment: @Ben Grossmann : At your convenience, would you ( or anyone else ) mind writing an answer for 1) and 2) ?  There is an answer to both questions at the link below ( page 15, fourth question ) but I don't follow either of them.  Thanks so much and I apologize for bothering you.  https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2021/REUPapers/Adler.pdf  I tried to write a question earlier but it got rejected ? Maybe because it's the same as the question here ?

Comment: @markleeds As the message on [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4786004/81360) indicates, it was closed due to a lack of context. If you edit your question to give an indication of what you've tried, it might be reopened.

Comment: Hi Ben. I re-wrote the question. I don't know if that will make it be available but I hope so ? I'm pretty lost regarding the conflicting answers so I haven't tried anything worth showing. But I did explain the conflict more clearly. Thanks for the advice.